# boost::variant visitor chooses the wrong overload

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant, apply-visitor

Why does the following print out `"A boolean!"`? I realise there are some weird conversion going on, since if I explicitly construct a std::string I get the correct behavior. But why does overload resolution choose `visitor::operator()(bool)` in the following case?

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <string>

typedef boost::variant<bool, std::string> type;

struct visitor : public boost::static_visitor<> {
    void operator()(bool b) const {
        std::cout << "A boolean!" << std::endl;
    }

    void operator()(const std::string& str) const {
        std::cout << "A string!" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    type t = "I am a string";
    t.apply_visitor(visitor());

    return 0;
}
```

I am running Visual Studio 2012 (CTP or not gives the same result)

Comment: FTR the `apply_visitor` member is not part of the public interface. You're supposed to use the freestanding version: `apply_visitor(visitor(), t)`.

Comment: Thanks @LucDanton. Missed that when I read the documentation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're initialisng `t` with a (type that decays to) `const char*`. Converting a pointer to `bool` is a standard conversion, while converting `const char*` to `std::string` is a user-defined conversion. The standard conversion takes precedence.